# How to prevent saving the same file multiple times in the memory

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

i want to read files (1 gb) per byte by using MemoryMappedFile from couple of threads (and processes ! ), my example code:

```
static unsafe void T()
{
    MemoryMappedFile mmf = null;
    var mmfName = "q1";
    var fname = @"%file_name%";

    lock (Lock)
    {
        try
        {
            mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(mmfName, MemoryMappedFileRights.Read, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
            Console.WriteLine("ok - open");
        }
        catch
        {
            FileStream fs = null;
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(fname, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4 * 1024, true);
                mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs, mmfName, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read, null, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, false);
                Console.WriteLine("ok - load");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fail");
            }
        }
    }

    var size = new System.IO.FileInfo(fname).Length;

    byte* ptr = (byte*)0;
    var vh = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read).SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle;
    vh.AcquirePointer(ref ptr);

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        var t = *(ptr + (int)rnd.Next(0, (int)size));
    }
}
```

and code to run the test:

```
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(T, T, T);

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

app output:

```
ok - load
ok - open
ok - open
```

The problem that my app takes 3 gb in memory (working set). So it copies file 3 times in memory. I want only one copy in memory (1 gb) for "ok - load" thread, and no copies for reading ("ok - open") threads.

Any ideas? (c#, 4.5, vs12, win7)

Thanks for help

Comment: Why don't you read the file from the main thread?

Comment: 1) I wonder what I'm doing wrong 2) threads is the simplifying example, i have the same situation with duplicating in memory in different processes

Comment: You should an issue cause currently I don't see one. You are duplicating the info, and then ask why it is duplicated...

Comment: I allocate only one segment in virtual memory, named "q1". Then I load  1 gb file in it. Then I want to get data from my "q1" segment (from other threads or processes). I suppose, that i have only one segment, but in fact I have 3 segments, why?

Comment: What's the problem with it being mapped and using 3gb working set? I don't think that means it's using 3gb of physical memory.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars thanks, good question; I don't know, process explorer says: http://wish-master.ru/transf/2013-09-12_182423.png (physical!). And a lot of page faults.. Anyway, I think, it's not normal, and I do something wrong way..

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars, and I am not sure, but some more problems are able to be on 32 bit OS.